# Auto Increment Field

Tags: ms-access, auto-increment

I am trying to implement a simple table in MS - ACCESS where im using two PK's for say a WEATHER table.

> PK LOCATION
>   PK ID
>   DATE
>   TEMPERATURE

I wish to increment the id based on the location, so if PARIS has 2 rows then the next would be for example 3, and if there is a new entry for Location then it would be 1.

very much like this [link](https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-two-columns-primary-key-with-auto-increment/)

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: *using two PK's* Impossible. PK + UNIQUE - possible. Composite PK (the pair is PK whereas each single may be non-unique) - possible.

Comment: By link - it is MySQL extension. Moreover, it is specific to one engine only - to MyISAM, and is not applicable to any other engine. So it cannot be reproduced in MS Access without additional code.